# Can xmlHttpRequest access the Authorization header in Firefox

Tags: javascript, authentication, xmlhttprequest

I may be missing something obvious... but

I am trying to enhance the native subversion http access with a greasemonkey plugin. At the moment I am using CGI scripts to run PROPFIND etc. This subverts security although it does work.

I have downloaded a Javascript DAV client that will do all that I want from http://debris.demon.nl/projects/davclient.js/. Assuming I can use the user credentials already supplied, I should be able to get extended subversion information using javascript with correct security.

We run Basic authentication on the subversion server and I do not know how to make the xmlHttpRequest in this library inherit the pre-existing browser authentication details. The xmlHttpRequest returns 401 although the calling page is authenticated and on the same domain.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a `Authorization` header manually using [`.setRequestHeader(header, value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader%28%29).

According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send%28%29-method):

> If the user agent supports HTTP Authentication and `Authorization` is not in the list of author request headers [set by `setRequestHeader`], it should consider requests originating from the `XMLHttpRequest` object to be part of the protection space that includes the accessed URIs and send `Authorization` headers and handle `401 Unauthorized` requests appropriately.

This seems to mean that if a user has already supplied authentication credentials for a resource, XHR will automatically use them.

Answer (score 0):

See [MDN XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader%28%29).